# Chown failure on Mac when attempting to install mobile device drivers for Appium via homebrew

Tags: macos, permissions, appium, homebrew, chown

After Appium did not recognize uid, I tried installing it with this command:

```
brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD
```

That gave me the following error:

```
Error: /usr/local/Homebrew is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Homebrew back to your
user account:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - > 
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/libimobiledevice.formula.lock
```

So, i copypastad and ran that chown command. It does not complain and seems to run. But, when I run the first command again, I still get the same error message.

Could someone help me resolve this?

edit:
I ran this command:
ls -ld /usr/local/Homebrew

This was the output:
drwxr-xr-x  17 1791192515  wheel  544 Mar  2 12:08 /usr/local/Homebrew

I ran this command:
ls -l /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/libimobiledevice.formula.lock

This was the output:
No such file or directory

Comment: There are other reasons why Homebrew wouldn't be writable, besides ownership. Please `ls -ld /usr/local/Homebrew`  and `ls -l /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/libimobiledevice.formula.lock`so we can check out the perms.

Comment: I ran those. That second directory doesn't seem to exist. How would I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are the steps I took to solve this problem

sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
then:
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
then:
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
Before trying again to run:
brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD